# Comparacao dando errada C++

Tags: c++, lógica

Estou fazendo um joguinho pra treinar escrita, mas na parte lógica para comparar a frase criada com a frase escrita o programa acusa que está errado para todas as respostas.
Como podem ver no código, já tentei converter novamente as variaveis para o mesmo tipo e mesmo assim nada.

O comparador está na main, mas deixei o código todo, pois acredito que o erro possa estar  na função que retorna a palavra.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>
#include <typeinfo>


std::string time(){

    time_t now = time(0);
    char* dt = ctime(&now);
    return dt;     }

int Random_Return (std::vector<std::string> Vec){

    int Vec_Max_Size = Vec.size();
    int Random_Return = rand() % Vec_Max_Size;

    return Random_Return;
}

std::string Gerador_De_Palavra(int Dificuldade){

    std::string Frase_Final;

    switch (Dificuldade)
    {
    case 1:
        Dificuldade = 3;
        break;
    case 2:
        Dificuldade = 6;
        break;
    case 3:
        Dificuldade = 10;
        break;
    case 4:
        Dificuldade = 15;
        break;
    case 5:
        Dificuldade = 30;
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    std::vector<std::string> Comida_Root = {"Abobrinha",
        "Marmelo",  "Tangerina",    "Carne de porco",   "Leite",    "Noz",  "Maracuja",
        "Peixe",    "Espargos",     "Cebola",   "Damasco",  "Morango",  "Sardinha",
        "Batatas",  "Aveia",    "Amora",    "Cereais",  "Cereja",  "Tomate",    "Abobrinha", 
        "Abobrinha",    "Pao",   "Figo",    "Tamareira",      "Pera",  "Ovos", "Coco" };

    std::vector<std::string> Profissoes_Root = {
        "Empresario",  "Youtuber",    "Arqueologa",  "Arquiteto",   "Jardineiro",  
        "Motorista",   "Construtor",  "Advogada",    "Enfermeira",  "Professor",
        "Astronauta",  "Guarda vida", "Ator",    "Dependente",  "Vendedora",   "Maquinista",  
        "Dona de casa",    "Escritor",    "Construtor",  "Piloto"};

    std::vector<std::string> Geometria_Root = {
        "Trapezio",    "Quadrado",    "Meia lua",    "Paralelogramo",   "Pentagono",    "Nonagono", 
        "Octagono",    "Atravessar",  "Oval",   "Losango",  "Retangulo",    "Estrela"};

    std::vector<std::string> Aleatorias_Root = {
    "projeto",  "desenhar", "cliente",  "Escreva",  "representar",  "reconhecer",   "rapidamente",
    "mover",    "musica",   "Principal",    "nacao",    "tudo",     "virar",    "longe",    "viver",
    "Forte",    "vestem",   "cultura",      "Formato",      "mentira",  "metade",   "resultado",
    "aprender", "ataque",    "sangue",  "estude",   "opcao",    "conhecimento",     "despesas", "perna"};

    srand(time(NULL));                  
    
    std::string Comida_Rand, Profissoes_Rand, Geometria_Rand, Aleatorias_Rand;

    for (int iterations = 0; iterations < Dificuldade; iterations++){
        
        int Rand_Choices = rand() % 4;

        int Rand_Comida = rand() % 27;     int Rand_Profissoes = rand() % 21; 
        int Rand_Geometria = rand() % 12;   int Rand_Aleatorias = rand() % 27; 

            switch (Rand_Choices){
            
                case 0:
                    
                    Profissoes_Rand += Profissoes_Root[Random_Return(Profissoes_Root)];
                    Frase_Final += Profissoes_Rand;
                    Frase_Final += " ";
                    Profissoes_Rand.clear();
               
                case 1:
                    
                    Comida_Rand += Comida_Root[Random_Return(Comida_Root)];
                    Frase_Final += Comida_Rand;
                    Frase_Final += " ";
                    Comida_Rand.clear();
               
                case 2:
                    
                    Geometria_Rand += Geometria_Root[Random_Return(Geometria_Root)];
                    Frase_Final += Geometria_Rand;
                    Frase_Final += " ";
                    Geometria_Rand.clear();
               
                case 3:
                    
                    Aleatorias_Rand += Aleatorias_Root[Random_Return(Aleatorias_Root)];
                    Frase_Final += Aleatorias_Rand;
                    Frase_Final += " ";
                    Aleatorias_Rand.clear();}

    }

    return Frase_Final;

}

int main(){

    std::string Comparar_Frase;
    

    for(int iteratorML = 0; iteratorML < 3; iteratorML++){
            
            std::string Frase_Recebida = Gerador_De_Palavra(1);
            std::cout<<Frase_Recebida;
            
            std::cout<<std::endl; std::getline(std::cin, Comparar_Frase);
                
            const char* Palavra_Recebida = Frase_Recebida.c_str();
            const char* Palavra_Escrita = Comparar_Frase.c_str();

                if(Palavra_Recebida == Palavra_Escrita){
                    exit(1);   }

                else {std::cout<<"algo deu errado";
                    std::cout<<std::endl<<std::endl<<Palavra_Recebida;
                    std::cout<<std::endl<<Palavra_Escrita;

                    std::cout<<std::endl<<typeid(Palavra_Escrita).name()<<std::endl<<typeid(Palavra_Recebida).name();
                    exit(1);} }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: notou que escreveu uma função `time()` que chama `time(0)` e que incluiu `time.h'?  Seu programa está incrivelmente complicado e frágil. E é basicamente um programa em C que usa `cin` e `cout`